# Blackberry - MDS cache and timeout configuration

Tags: networking, blackberry, mds-cs

For normal HTTP connections does the MDS waits till the complete request is finished (collects all data) and sends the data afterward to the client?
When I make an http connection to a server containing a file of around 5mb, I have to wait for a considerable amount of time before I get the response. Sometimes the connection also times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control mds timeout by mds config parameter [IPPP.queue.flow control.timeout (default = 60000)](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devjournals/resources/journals/nov_2003/calling_all_networks.jsp#ip)

> If the handheld does not send an acknowledgement within the time frame specified here, the Mobile Data Service discards all content pending to the handheld. This parameter is measured in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If your requests are going through a BIS server and no transcoding is taking place, you won't have to wait for MDS to buffer all the data.  But if your requests are going through BES older then 5.0.3, then it probably will be buffered even if no transcoding is happening.  Make sure transcoding isn't taking place unless you need it to.